# Notepad++ plugin sourcecookifier doesn't recognize makefiles

Tags: notepad++

I've just installed sourcecookifier, works well besides makefiles. It recognizes .mk extension but doesn't just "Makefile" or "makefile". Seems like the problem is in leading dot. How to make sourcecookifier recognize makefiles?

Comment: The answer to your question *"Have anyone had this issue?"* is likely to be either YES or NO. How would such an answer help you. Please [edit] your question to explain what you really want. The [help] centre pages contain advice on how to write a good question that is likely to produce useful answers.

Comment: Npp recognizes the file language only by its extension, not by its content.

Comment: @Toto it's clear to me but how to make sourcecookifier work with makefiles if it filenames often don't contain an extension

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer myself. Fixed this by adding "makefile." as the extension in the Lanuage settings.

Comment: How have you done this? I still get 'ERROR: There is no matching extension for this file in your language settings'

Comment: @V15I0N In the language settings select Make and add "makefile." to the Extension list

Comment: Now I've seen the difference, thanks! I didn't notice the . at the end of "makefile." before.